# Руссификация COSMOS C#

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно заставить COSMOS C# правильно
отображать русские буквы?

COSMOS – это операционная система написанная на C#. Устанавливаешь пакет под свой Visual Studio и пишешь систему.

Comment: Эээ, а что такое COSMOS?

Comment: @VladD, [похоже вот](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmos_(%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0))

Comment: Спасибо VladD, но ваш ответ мне не помог или я чего-то не понял

Comment: @Сергей: Ну, это же был не ответ, а уточняющий комментарий. Ответов пока никто не дал :-(

Comment: @VladD для уточнения пишу, я использую Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate eng и пакет CosmosUserKit92560 вот собственно и всё. Значит в коде пишу Console.WriteLine("пример"), а он мне абрукадабру выдаёт.